# Plot spectograms for all .wav files in a folder using python (in jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, scipy, jupyter-notebook, librosa

i've got the following code that creates a spectogram for a specific file, pretty simple. what i want to discover is if there is a away to plot a spectogram for all the files inside a folder without having to copy paste the spectogram lines of code and change the name of the audio file in each one (i know about glob but I couldn't apply it here).

```
#import the pyplot and wavfile modules 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile 

# Read the wav file (mono)
samplingFrequency, signalData = wavfile.read('sounds/wams20_hat1.wav')

# Plot the signal read from wav file
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

plt.title('Spectrogram')
plt.specgram(signalData,Fs=samplingFrequency)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

inside the folder sounds/ I have a 100 .wav files, so i'm trying to find an "ecological" way to achieve a 100 spectograms of this .wav files with the less possible number of lines of code. hope this sounds clear to you

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that takes the path to the audio to load, and returns a matplotlib Figure. Then call this in a loop for each file in the directory (which you can get using `glob.glob` or `os.listdir`).

The function should probably create the matplotlib Figure and axis explicitly, using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))`. Then render the spectrogram into it. Using `librosa.load` to get the audio and `librosa.display.specshow(ax=ax)` is a bit nicer than using scipy/matplotlib directly. [librosa webpage](https://librosa.github.io/)